What tag for questions that are simply not physics?
I just saw a question with a whole set of tags which were completely inappropriate as the question was simply off-topic (it would be generous to call it a personal philosophy).  I thought to delete the tags, because we don't want this question turning up in searches for these topic.
Problem: I have to put at least one tag in.  I cannot leave tags empty.
So what tag is appropriate for a question that's going to be closed as off-topic and has nothing to do with physics?

@KyleKanos Thanks for that.  Do we know the timescale for "eventually" ?  Months ?  Years ?

Sorry for long delay, work & family beckon. 10 days is the usual time scale, could be sooner if those with >10K rep vote to delete on it, but that seems somewhat rare anymore

If a question is migrated to Phys.SE with no existing tags, it automatically gets tagged with the tag untagged, so that also seems to be the appropriate tag in OP's case.
Note that due to clean-ups, the tag untagged might not currently exists and has to be created, which requires 1000 reputation points.

And tagging a post with [tag:untagged] creates a metaphysical crisis since what was [tag:untagged] is now [tag:tagged] so it isn't [tag:untagged]. With great power (1000 rep) comes great responsibility.

@Jon Custer: Ha-ha. A version of Russell's paradox.
